# В чем различия между семантикой, грамматикой, пунктуацией?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, семантика

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но хотелось бы узнать особенности каждого из разделов языка на каком-нибудь примере, предложении, чтобы были очевидны черты каждого из разделов.

"Шел дождь, и, надеясь я пройти по улицу, лицу лужу упасть в неё не дал"
"Кот, который, черный и полосатый, шел по улице, был не нашим"

Comment: Пунктуация — это знаки препинания. Что здесь непонятного? Как можно сравнивать с семантикой и грамматикой?! Отличия (в заголовке) и черты (ниже) — это разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

СЕМАНТИКА — раздел семиотики и логики, исследующий отношение языковых выражений к обозначаемым объектам и выражаемому содержанию.
ГРАММАТИКА 1) собрание законов и правил употребления устного и письменного языка.
ПУНКТУАЦИЯ — правила употребления дополнительных письменных знаков (знаков препинания), служащих для обозначения ритмики и мелодики фразы, иначе фразовой интонации.
Ваши примеры.

1. [Шел дождь, и, надеясь я пройти по улицу, лицу лужу упасть в неё не дал] Грамматика: имеем сложносочиненное предложение с союзом "и". Пунктуация: ошибка - нет точки в конце. Семантика: Первая часть предложение понятна (капли воды падают с неба)  грамматических и пунктуационных ошибок нет.
   Вторая часть. Грамматика есть деепричастный оборот с неправильным положением подлежащего, с несогласованными предлогом к существительному. Семантика: восстанавливаем деепричастный оборот: [..., и я, надеясь пройти на улицу, ...] Пунктуация: ставим правильно запятые.
   Анализ остатка. [...,и я,..., лицу лужу упасть в неё не дал] Семантика: остаток  это бессмысленный набор слов из которых невозможно составить осмысленную фразу.
   Вывод. В данном примере имеет смысл только первая часть сложно сочиненного предложения. Вторая часть явного смысла не имеет. Она представляет собой набор слов, частично структурированных грамматически.
2. [Кот, который, черный и полосатый, шел по улице, был не нашим]
   Семантика: чужой кот шел по улице. Ошибка в его цвете - не может один объект быть и черным и полосатым. Грамматика: сложноподчиненное предложение, с неправильным местоположением уточняющих слов. Пунктуация: нет точки в конце; лишние запятые вокруг слов, что не на месте. Исправляем ошибки и получаем:
   {Черно-полосатый кот, который шел по улице, был не нашим.}
   Такая окраска у животных бывает:

> Черно-полосатый морской крайт (Laticauda semifasciata), также
> известный обычно как китайская морская змея или эрабу...

Answer (score 1):

Грамматика - это искусство письма, греческое слово. Это умение записывать речь и прочие мысли, с целью передачи её контекстного смысла, нужного значения, правильности написания слов - орфографии, интонационных моментов и пауз - пунктуации, и прочее верное членение текста на предложения, абзацы и части.

Пример: *Дьете Пешити прально исчьо.*

Пунктуация отвечает за паузы и интонации, которые можно будет прочесть. Можно сравнить с музыкой, там есть ноты обозначающие звучание нужного тона и между этими нотами бывают промежутки, иначе нота длилась бы бесконечно. Паузы между нотами и длины нот обеспечивают характерный ритмический рисунок. Без пунктуации текст был бы монолитным, если вспомните как в старых фильмах имитируют голос роботов, то они произносят каждое слово монотонно, без пауз, сплошняком - это пример, как не нужно делать или писать, для этого и нужна пунктуация. Ну и пунктуация облегчает считывания текста, так как слова разбиваются на группы слов - фразы, которые в свою очередь выстраиваются в согласование между собой.

Пример, ну, скажем, стихотворение в одно предложение: [*Я пришел к тебе с приветом...*](https://www.culture.ru/poems/12683/ya-prishel-k-tebe-s-privetom)

Синтаксис также является разделом грамматики, который изучает отношения между словами в предложениях или словосочетаниях: какое слово является главным, какое зависимым, где в предложении главные члены, где второстепенные, расположение этих слов и тп. То есть синтаксис - это  соединение слов в "различные синтаксические конструкции" - умение строить предложение. Синтаксис, очевидно, связан с пунктуацией.

Орфография - ну это просто верное написание тех или иных слов, потому что есть слова похожие, чтобы не была каши из букв.

Семантика - это раздел семиотики... А что такое семиотика тогда? Нет, семантика - это такой раздел языкознания, в который изучает значение слов, от СЕМА - знак. Семантика связана с логикой(и прочим гипертекстом) - некая математизация языка, как наука она оформилась только ~150 лет назад. На семантике держится по сути всё программирование машин и ... людей. Слово-знак - это почти тоже, что слово команда, ну и плюс доп инфа. Семантика изучает способы передачи и считывания языковой информации.

Более древние досемантические разделы назывались этимология - происхождение корней слов, толкование - понимания слов, фраз, идиом, идеи текста, а не информации. В чем разница? Вот представьте, вы идете из пункта А в пункт Б, а дорог нет. Вы ориентируетесь по звёздам, по мху на деревьях, наслаждаетесь видами природы, закатами, слушаете пение лесных птиц, кроме того у вас есть встречи с другими людьми, с которыми в - общаетесь(а не просто обмениваетесь шаблонными "привет, как дела, как погода"), - но процесс перемещения, конечно, не быстрый, но а нафига вам вообще из А в Б? А вот семантика - это когда есть дороги, а раз есть дороги, значит есть дорожные знаки, чтобы аварий было меньше, вокруг с вами едет куда-то куча других людей по своим делам, все что-то обозначают - сигналят светом или биром, или вообще матюкаются через открытое окошко, пробки там тоже бывают, аварии все равно бывают, дорога разрушится - вообще беда. И все спешат из А в Б не успевая даже по сторонам поглядеть, так как водитель должен следить за дорогой и иной "информации" не должен в принципе усваивать.

Ненужная лирика:

*Вот, примерно, что такое семантика и все остальное - досемантическое. Особенно мне нравятся семантические корни, например, в слове изумление корень изумл, а не ум. Или еще такая штука, семантикой любят называть смысловое значение слов, где смысл заменяет(почему-то) знак. Хотя смысл слова "смысл"(да и вообще слов) это не значение, а причина этих самых слов, то есть мысли. Сюда можно докинуть полешко науки. Дело в том, что по Павлову(который собачек резал и наблюдал за реакциями) у людей, в отличие от прочих животных, есть не только первая сигнальная система - реакции на внешние раздражители, но и так называемая вторая сигнальная, которая речь слова которыми мы говорим, но не думаем, потому что слова это лишь оформленные мысли, а мысли это прожитые, отрефлексированные чувства. Так вот, по Павлову, который собачек резал, вторая сигнальная это надстройка над первой сигнальной, грубо говоря если у человеческого организма нет опыта взаимодействия с окружающим миром, который от смог бы отрефлексировать с помощью мысли и образовать понимание происходящего - создать образы процессов, то он не понимает смысла слов и общение с миром сводится к следованию правилам семантического "ПДД", ну а ум человека мыслящего превращается в мозги индивидуума...*

Русский язык по ряду причин с семантикой не дружит, так что пример из английского: ["Every real signifier is, as such, a signifier that signifies nothing. The more the signifier signifies nothing, the more indestructible it is."](https://nosubject.com/Signifier#cite_note-2)Lacan.

А да, семантика нужна для автоперевода через стандарты языковых форм в различных языках, поэтому автоперевод фразы: "Каждое реальное означающее само по себе является означающим, которое ничего не означает. Чем больше означающее ничего не означает, тем более оно неразрушимо".

Думаю, этот автоперевод достаточно корректно передает содержание.

Но вот возьмём того же Фета и пропустим его через автопереводчик туда-сюда, на выходе получим следующее:

Английский:

> Я пришел к вам с приветом
>
> Скажи, что солнце взошло
>
> Что такое горячий свет
>
> Простыни трепетали;

Арабский:

> Я пришел к вам с приветом,
>
> Чтобы сказать вам, что солнце взошло,
>
> это жаркий свет
>
> Трепещущие листья;

Греческий:

> Я пришел к вам с приветом
>
> Скажи, что вышло солнце
>
> Что такое теплый свет?
>
> Листья дрожат.

Китайский:

> Я пришел к вам с приветом,
>
> Я говорю вам, что солнце взошло,
>
> Это тепловая лампа
>
> Развевающиеся простыни;

Немецкий:

> Я пришел к тебе с уважением,
>
> Чтобы сказать, что солнце взошло,
>
> Что это жаркий свет.
>
> Его мучили на листьях;

Видно что: ТЫ сохранилось только в немецком, листья стали простынями, потому что калька английского, ну и стих уже не торт; синтаксис также нарушен, хотя орфографически слова написаны грамотно. И если бы не простыни, то в целом можно было бы догадаться о чем идет речь, но, само-собой без следования семантике напрямую, а воспринимая это как семантическую ошибку, попытаться восстановить оригинал.

Ну и надо отдать должное Яше, так как, если убрать строфы и написать в одно предложение, то простыни исчезают(английский), а вот Гоголь уверенно переводит простыни, хотя у Яши есть иные артефакты:

Яша:

Я пришел к вам с приветствиями, чтобы сказать вам, что солнце взошло, что оно трепещет горячим светом на листьях;

Гоголь:

Я пришел к вам с приветом, чтобы сказать вам, что солнце взошло, что оно затрепетало горячим светом на простынях;

Comment: Язык возник и служит для передачи информации от человека к человеку. Информации, которая обеспечивала прежде всего выживание особи. А без смысла, без семантики языков нет.  Грамматика и пунктуация без семантики дает только *глокая куздра штеко будланула бокра и кудрячит бокрёнка* . И с помощью таких грамматических конструкций не узнаешь где купить молока.

Comment: @Василий А зная одну лишь информацию не узнаешь откуда это молоко берется, ведь может оказаться, что оно не самородится в магазине, представляете? Семантика головного мозга ограничивает человеческое бытие до функционала курьера, передатчика информации. Смысл слова и значение слово - вещи разные, благо в русском языке есть для этого разные слова, я вроде подробно объяснил, вы вообще читали мой ответ или так, мимо проходили и решили оставить напоминалку - передать информацию потомкам о себе?

Comment: @Василий "Язык возник и служит для передачи информации от человека к человеку" примерно тоже самое, что сказать "а головой едят". Какой-то бессмысленный набор букв, объединенный в подобие слов. Вы можете лучше, я уверен, постарайтесь. Когда возник, откуда, по какой причине, для чего передавать информацию, иди "а че они этого не умели что ли"? Наконец, что такое эта информация, чтобы ей делиться? Какая-то банальная бессвязность. Простите, за резкость, меня просто раздражает, когда повторяют какие-то тупые, бессмысленные фразы, суть которых сами не понимают,  "делятся информацией", простите.

Comment: @Василий "Каждое реальное означающее само по себе является означающим, которое ничего не означает. Чем больше означающее ничего не означает, тем более оно неразрушимо" - вот это про информацию. informacion, "act of informing, communication of news," from Old French informacion, enformacion "advice, instruction," from Latin informationem (nominative informatio) "outline, concept, idea," Информация - это инструкция, контуры смыслов, знания достаточные для функционирования без понимания сути, совет от идиота - коробки с этикетками, но без содержания. Вот этим вы и делитесь?

Comment: Извините нам с Вами бесполезно разговаривать на темы информации и семантики. Эти термины мы понимаем совершенно по разному. Всё что написано, от великих книг до продажной рекламы, всё это - информация.  Все идеи и смыслы  зафиксированные в них - это тоже информация.  И даже Ваши мысли - это тоже информация. Любое общение людей - это всегда передача информации.  А семантикой занимались еще неандертальцы, когда объясняли детям, что вот этот звук обозначает мамонта, а этот нашу пещеру. Для Вас это тупые бессмысленные фразы, а для меня то с чем я привык работать. Адью!

Comment: @Василий "является означающим, которое ничего не означает" - именно это значение соответствует в вашем "понимании" слову информация, то есть информация - это всё и везде, но которое внезапно ничего само по себе не значит. В этом и есть основная фишка семантики, она базируется на вот таких вот понятиях-пустышках. Раньше люди верили в Бога, а теперь в информацию, демократию, свободу, деньги... ну и прочую бессмыслицу. Разговаривать конечно смысла нет, потому что спор с верующими в принципе дело бесполезное и не нужное, хотят люди верить - пусть верят, иначе какой смысл в вере, если она не слепая

Comment: @Василий ну я не спорю, вы скорее всего умеете работать с семантикой. Но чем бы ни была семантика, для меня "продажная реклама" и исповеди настоящих писателей вещи просто не сочетаемые с точки зрения смысла, буквы те же, слова похожие - а смысл, извините, иной. Фиксация идеи не содержит самой идеи, максимум идеологию, идея она содержится внутри читателя и слова могут быть обращены к ней, только тогда он прочтет их осмысленно. Увы, научить мыслить невозможно.

Comment: Фиксация идеи не содержит самой идеи, максимум идеологию, ...   Буратино, Вы прочитайте что Вы написали: Фиксация идеи не содержит самой идеи, максимум **совокупность идей** !!  *Увы, научить мыслить невозможно.* Неверно читайте ТРИЗ Альтшуллера.

Comment: @Василий я не так написал, я написал учение об идее, а не саму идею

Comment: @Василий 1796, "science of ideas," originally "philosophy of the mind which derives knowledge from the senses" (as opposed to metaphysics), from French idéologie "study or science of ideas," Meaning "systematic set of ideas, doctrines through which the world is interpreted" was in use in English by 1907. Вот каким языком вы разговариваете. семантика появилась в конце 19 века -начале 20. Это её место по праву, вместе с фашизмом, нацизмом, глобализмом и двумя мировыми войнами.

Comment: @Василий генезис идеи по семантике проследить невозможно. Поэтому и понять означающие без означаемого не представляется возможным. Вы вы бездумно повторяете фарш из  ничего не значащих слов, потому что даже не знаете, кто это придумал, по какой причине и для чего. Вы думаете что эти слова были всегда, семантика у неандертальцев, социум, частная собственность... но нет. Если в произносимом слове нет частицы твоей души - это просто "передача информации" попугаем.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к вопросу**

Любопытный вопрос, но не очень ясный. Если вас интересует **общее понимание**, то изложить все это в коротком ответе достаточно сложно. Рассуждать здесь можно до бесконечности, так и не убедив собеседника в чем-либо. Это хорошо видно, если даже не вникать в содержание уже данных ответов. Просто люди будут говорить о разных вещах, и если хочется послушать, то это вариант для беседы. Но вопрос можно рассматривать более **конкретно, в практическом плане**.

Русская пунктуация основана **на трех принципах** — семантическом, структурно-грамматическом и интонационном. Вот эту тему можно разобрать четко, хотя в источниках по языку она тоже решается **неоднозначно.** Но это то, что действительно важно для нашей грамотности (как в устной, так и письменной речи). И это актуально, так как касается каждого из нас. Не составляет большого труда найти ошибки в ваших примерах. **А потом что с этим делать?**

В то же время в наших ответах постоянно приходится сталкиваться с тремя указанными планами, и ошибки делаются постоянно. Постановку каждой **СПОРНОЙ запятой** можно объяснить, используя эти темы. И вот тогда становится действительно ясно, насколько безупречно мы их понимаем.

К примеру, **семантику** упрощенно можно определить как содержание речи с учетом ее коммуникативной функции: что говорится, кому и зачем говорится (тема и рема в простом предложении). А семиотика — это особая наука.

Кстати, вопрос общего плана могут даже закрыть как **несоответствующий** требованиям: вопрос должен быть строго по теме русского языка и на него можно дать конкретный ответ.